# Hide some form fields and feed it with data in the background

Tags: angular, ionic3, formbuilder

I want to hide this two fields from the user and feed it's data in the background. When i do console, i get undefined in those fields.

```
<form [formGroup]="fb" (ngSubmit)="createData()">
  <ion-item class="form-group">
    <ion-label floating>User name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [value]="username" id="username" class="form-control" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item class="form-group">
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet" formControlName="destinationid">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let destinationid of destinations" [value]="destinationid._id">{{destinationid._id}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```

My component's formbuilder is;

```
  username='swara';
  destinations = ['china','korea','japan'];
    this.fb = formBuilder.group({
  //some field removed
  username: [this.username],
  destinationid: formBuilder.array([this.destinationid])
});
```

Comment: If you want to hide them, simply remove them from your HTML. To update them, you can directly update the value of your form with `this.fb.patchValue({ destinationid: '4' })`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the 'hidden' attribute, it will set `display:none` in CSS for your HTML element without removing it from the DOM.

To use it you add `[hidden]="some boolean"`

```
<form [hidden]="some boolean" [formGroup]="fb" (ngSubmit)="createData()">
  <ion-item class="form-group">
    <ion-label floating>User name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [value]="username" id="username" class="form-control" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item class="form-group">
    <ion-select interface="action-sheet" formControlName="destinationid">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let destinationid of destinations" [value]="destinationid._id">{{destinationid._id}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</form>
```